# Put unable to ask question post in the Bulletin or pin to some location

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

There's been so many dupes lately, it'd be worth pinning somewhere.

Comment: You mean, besides it being featured on the front page under frequently asked questions?

Answer (score 7):

It is pinned somewhere. Right there in the notice they get that tells them they can't ask questions.

They get this nice link: http://goo.gl/C1Kwu

Which links to this nice answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998

On this nice FAQ question: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Most just don't care to read, and think that by coming here and asking a question we can magically lift this ban so they don't have to read or really do anything to fix the problem themselves.

Comment: Should I delete question. I apologize for never being so horrible that I haven't seen that notice.  ^_^

Comment: You can't. :) It has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Xaade RE: Bart -- Although, we could flag it for you. :-)

Comment: Nah, just accept the answer and bow your head in shame while we point and laugh.

Comment: @Bart Oh shame! Shame!!!!! and Agony!!!!!...... :(